# WPF/MVVM: Disable a Button's state when the ViewModel behind the UserControl is not yet Initialized?

Tags: wpf, button, icommand

I have a DocumentListView.Xaml with a ListBox and 3 Buttons.

Behind that UserControl sits a DocumentListViewModel with 3 Buttons and their Command Property bound to 3 RelayCommands.

I have 3 Controller like AdministrationController, BillingController, ReportController.

Every Controller has ObservableCollections like Customer 1 : N Order 1: N Document same for the other Controller.

In one Controller I have a special binding situation. When my DocumentListViewModel is not initialized by its parent ViewModel like OrderViewModel (because no orders are loaded/exist) then my UserControl has 3 buttons which are ENABLED. Ok the user can press the 3 buttons and nothing happens but still its very confusing and above all the consistency in my user interface is gone.

How can I set the Command of a Button as default to "Disabled" ?

Setting the Buttons IsEnabled property to false does not help because the button will stay forever in the disabled state. No CanExecute TRUE will set it to IsEnabled = true.

AND I do not want to introduce another property IsButtonEnabled... that stupid because then I have both worlds winforms and wpf behind my buttons logic... ICommand should be enough.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Or you can use a Style for the button to disable:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="DisablerButton">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Command" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: With your style how is the IsEnabled Property set to TRUE ?

Comment: Whenever the trigger is not-hit - the normal procedure is called. Ie. when the Command-property is set and the CanExecute evaluates to true.

Comment: Works! thats counts now! Thanks Goblin.

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting situation. Honestly I've never run into the case where the UI was loaded and interactive but the ViewModel was not yet bound.

However, ignoring that for a moment, you could potentially use a FallbackValue on your binding to bind to a globally available NullCommand or something that always returns false for its CanExecute method.

```
<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand, FallbackValue={StaticResource NullCommand}}" />
```

Comment: The problem is my DocumentListView is a UserControl used 3 times. When I do Command="{Binding SaveCommand, FallbackValue={x:Null}}" /> the SaveButton is still Enabled. But I would like to disable it via Commanding.

Comment: Right, my example relies upon a globally available NullCommand, not the x:Null value which as you noted will enable the button. In any event, Goblin's workaround is probably easier to implement.

Comment: This is an extremely nice solution, especially for Silverlight.