# WPF: MVVM - disable button if command is null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have binding on some command:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Save}" />
```

**Save** is command of some object that can be selected from list.
In initial state there is no any selected object so binding does not work and **CanExecute** does not invoked. How can i disable this button using MVVM?

Solution: [WPF/MVVM: Disable a Button's state when the ViewModel behind the UserControl is not yet Initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423746/wpf-mvvm-disable-a-buttons-state-when-the-viewmodel-behind-the-usercontrol-is-n/4424241#4424241)

Guys, thanks for your answers and sorry for duplication of question.

Comment: You could create a Style for the Button with a DataTrigger that disables the Button when {Binding Save} equals x:Null.

Comment: Thanks! I found the same solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423746/wpf-mvvm-disable-a-buttons-state-when-the-viewmodel-behind-the-usercontrol-is-n/4424241#4424241. But i can't mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks. I've added my comment as a "real answer" (and took the liberty of adding your link), so you can accept it now. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a trigger in XAML that disables the Button when the command equals `x:Null`.

An example can be found in the answer to this question: [WPF/MVVM: Disable a Button`s state when the ViewModel behind the UserControl is not yet Initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423746#4424241)

Answer (score 8):

Define a command that always return false to CanExecute. Declare it at a global position such as in your App.Xaml.  you can specify this empty-command then as the `FallbackValue` for all your command bindings you expect a null value first.

```
<Button Command="{Binding Save,FallbackValue={StaticResource KeyOfYourEmptyCommand}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll be able to achieve this.  However, an alternative would be to initialise the Command object initially with a basic ICommand where CanExecute simply returns False.  You could then replace this when you're ready to put the real command in place.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Create a NullToBooleanConverter and bind the `IsEnabled` property to the command, running it through the converter:

```
class NullToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null;      
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <Extentions:NullToBooleanConverter x:Key="NullToBooleanConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Button Content="Hello" IsEnabled="{Binding Save, Converter={StaticResource NullToBooleanConverter}}" />
```